# Jena-osgi 3.0.1 ExceptionInInitializerError processGlobalSystemProperties

Tags: java, jena

jena-osgi 3.0.1 ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() throws an ExceptionInInitializerError when we run the following code in a JUNIT (4.11) environment in Eclipse:

```
 // Convert the XML to RDF model
 StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
 Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
 model.read(stringReader, null, RDFLanguages.RDFXML.getLabel());
```

The stack trace is the following:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.EnvTDB.processGlobalSystemProperties(EnvTDB.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB.init(TDB.java:250)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB.start(InitTDB.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.lambda$init$40(JenaSystem.java:114)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:156)
    at org.apache.jena.system.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:111)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.<clinit>(ModelFactory.java:49)
    ... 25 more
```

The same code works if we use jena-tdb 3.0.1 instead of jena-osgi 3.0.1. We need to run our code in an OSGi environment (Servicemix) so it is critical that we get the OSGi piece working.

I've seen similar errors reported in Stack overflow but none of them have solved our problem. I'm thinking maybe we are missing a library? These are the jars we are importing with Maven:

1. org.apache.jena:jena-osgi:3.0.1
2. org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces:2.11.0_1
3. com.github.andrewoma.dexx:dexx-collections:0.2
4. commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3
5. commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
6. commons-io:commons-io:2.4
7. org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.2.5
8. xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01

NOTE: we tried to use Jena 3.1.0 OSGi and that one does work, BUT the JSON-LD is coming out weird when junit is run in maven (the xml namespace prefixes are stripped), but works fine in Eclipse.

Comment: By JSON, do you mean JSON-LD? otherwise what have xml namespaces go to do with JSON? Looks like a separate issue to the OSGi issue to me.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1164 is the fix for OSGi issues. This included upgrades to Dexx collections.

Comment: Yes, I did mean JSON-LD and yes it is a separate issue. I added that "note" just so it was clear that we have tried other versions and things are semi-working with other versions.

Comment: Looking over everything it does seem like we have to use version 3.1.0. If you make your comment as an answer Andy I will mark it as the correct one for future users to see. I'll make a new question about the strange prefix behavior we are noticing between Eclipse JUNIT and Maven JUNIT environments. Working to turn it into a minimum reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RobV's answer provides a solution for correctly packing the OSGi bundle to include all ServiceLoader files.

Upgrading to Jena 3.1.0 (specifically for [JENA-1164](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1164)) is the fix for jena-osgi issues with regard to finding ServiceLoader files in different OSGi frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem most likely relates to Jena System initialisation. It relies upon the `ServiceLoader` mechanism and so if you do not have the correct `META-INF/services/` resources present only parts of the system Will be set up and components like TDB which rely on other components can fail to initialise as a result.

You look to have the same issue as described in the following mailing list thread - [http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201603.mbox/%3C56E8817D.8080308@apache.org%3E]

The suggested solution there is as follows:

> The default is to use `ServiceLoader` which looks for `META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle`
>
> If your setup is a single jar then the contents of this from all
>   modules  needs to be combined:
>
> For example, Fuseki, which is a combined jar, has:
>
> ```
> org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB 
> org.apache.jena.riot.system.InitRIOT
> org.apache.jena.sparql.system.InitARQ
> org.apache.jena.system.InitJenaCore
> org.apache.jena.query.text.InitJenaText
> org.apache.jena.query.spatial.InitJenaSpatial
> ```
>
> It's done in the POM during shading with:
>
> ```
> <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"  />
> ```

Comment: Thanks for putting this, I up voted it. In the end however it is simpler to switch to 3.1.0.